# Is it possible to apply any encryption algorithm on ODBC?

Tags: database, algorithm, encryption, odbc

I want to know can we apply any customized encryption algorithm to ODBC?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is driver dependent if it uses cryptography when it "talks" with server. Some drivers I use (Informix, Oracle) do not use any cryptography, while others (PostgreSQL) offers SSL.

Of course you can use VPN with encryption and then transmission should be secure.

Or you can encrypt data in database.

But those solutions are not ODBC dependent.